# QProcess how to request windows UAC to bypass password using runAs for admin level commands from an admin account

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Question: Can anyone explain to me how to call UAC? At this point, I need to elevate a Powershell session. All of the other methods I've used in the past or see here require a password. I need to bypass the password. Please see the write up under the following function for more information:

```
void MainWindow::execute_command(QString param)
{
    // In this case assume param is simply Remove-LocalUser "User name"
    QProcess *process = new QProcess();
    QStringList params;
    QString command = "powershell";
    params << "-c" << "Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb runAs " << param;
    process->start(command, params);
    process->waitForFinished();
    process->kill();
}
```

If I try any admin-level command, it fails to execute within Powershell because the access gets denied. I'm aware of various methods that enable the elevation of user access. But as far as I know, all of those require the password to be input by the user. Any account that runs this program will be by default an Administrator or Domain Administrator; so, I hope that summoning UAC will enable the user to acknowledge and accept the elevation request to pull through an administrator Powershell.

Comment: *ShellExecuteExW* with *runas* in [*lpVerb*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfoa) ?

Comment: I have tried this as well but it didn't work. I'll reference this and try again https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea

Comment: use *ShellExecuteExW* with *runas* worked method. if *not work* you make some error in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, @RbMm was correct, my code was wrong:

```
void MainWindow::execute_command(QString param)
{
     SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};
     ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
     ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
     ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
     ShExecInfo.lpVerb = "runas";
     ShExecInfo.lpFile = TEXT("powershell.exe");
     ShExecInfo.lpParameters = TEXT("stuff..");
     ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
     ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
     ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
     ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
     WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
}
```

Summons the UAC prompt which allows me to elveate based on whether or not the user clicks the button labeled "yes" on UAC! Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 0):

The way I read your question you wish to avoid the UAC prompt entirely. This is not possible so long as you run the program from a interactive login session with UAC enabled on the system.

It is possible to avoid the need to enter the Administrator password by logging in to that account but you will still need a UAC prompt in order to run with the elevated Administrator token rather than the limited token that most programs use.

Note that if your program is a service then the program will run in a session that does not provide for the split user token and instead all programs will run with the complete token (although most privileges will still be disabled until/unless a process enables them).

Comment: No sorry, I want to call up the UAC prompt so that I can avoid having to either build out a service account, redirect stdin or push a users password through. Trouble is that I can't figre out how to make the prompt popup.